# Differences between answers I get from Different Calculators

Tags: trigonometry

I find that when I calculate $\cos{1}$ in ...

- Google: $0.540$
- Ubuntu: $0.998$

I believe its different units. But I wonder which should I be using? The question I am doing is use bisection method to find $\cos{x} = x$ when $x \in [0,1]$. For now, I am using Google as its close to what I get from a [Graphing Utility](https://www.abettercalculator.com/c)

Comment: Google is using radians and Ubuntu is using degrees. Which one you want to use depends on where you got the question from, but I assume radians were intended.

Comment: Google is using radians; Ubuntu is using degrees. I would stick with radians.

Comment: Grownups use radians.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Qiaochu and The Chaz say in the comments, the difference is because Google is showing you the cosine of 1 radian, while Ubuntu is showing you the cosine of 1 degree.

As The Chaz said, I suggest you stick to radians, in particular if you are doing anything related to calculus. The assertion that $(\sin x)'=\cos x$, $(\cos x)'=-\sin x$ is not true if $x$ is in degrees.